# Adding orthophoto layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, orthophoto

I have tracks (just waypoints) from my GPS in gpx format. I also have orthophoto pictures in tif format, that I would like to make a layer with
I use QGIS (1.8.0)
actually i know how to put it in, but it shows wrong 
(coordinate system = WGS 84/EPSG 4326 - europe)

my goal is to put together all waypoints and export as a shp file.

Answer (score 3):

GPX format is always in `EPSG:4326`, so nothing wrong about that.

If the orthophotos are correctly georeferenced, it should be no problem to add them to the project. Make sure you choose the right CRS for that layer, and enable on-the-fly-reporjection under `Settings -> Project settings`. It does not have to be the same CRS as the GPX layer is.

You can add Openlayers plugin and Google or bing satellite imagery to see if your layers are in the right position. For that plugin, the **project** CRS must be `EPSG:3857`. The **layers** can still have other CRS.

If your orthophotos are correctly georeferenced, they should line up with the satellite imagery. If they do not, you can use the georeferencer to re-georeference them by referencing with points on the satellite background.

To export your waypoints as shapefile, rightclick on the layer and `Save As ...` You can even select another CRS in that step.

Comment: how do I know, if orthophotos are correctly georeferenced? + I was looking for info, wow to add openlayers (and google Earth image), but was too complicated. Otherwise BIG!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your ortho layer is in a different projection (ie: utm) you can right click the ortho layer and set projection from CRS, this will project the QGIS project into the ortho layer projection